# Kendo Grid Export To Excel With Border

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Currently kendo grid can easily export it's data to excel but doesn't show border among the columns at all. How can I format the excel worksheets so that the data will be in full border? Are there any setting related to worksheet customization in order to achieved that? Thanks

You can view some examples by kendo in the link below:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export#

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "full border"? In the Telerik example there is a border between columns B & C. Is that what you are needing?

Comment: In Excel, there is a border for cell. The thing is, how to set that border when i export kendo grid to excel. Currently, when i export there is no border is set. Is there any setting to change or any kind of trick to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit [a few things](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/excel-export#customize-the-excel-document) about the data rendering such as right to left allignement but you can't customize the style of the worksheet.

From the kendo [grid documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/excel-export#limitations) about customization of the Excel exported from the kendo grid and it's limitations:

**Limitations**

**Column Templates**

The Grid does not use column templates during the Excel export—**it exports only the data**. The reason for this behavior is that a column template might contain arbitrary HTML which cannot be converted to Excel column values. For more information on how to use a column template that does not contain HTML, refer to this column template example.